# Make SublimeLinter flake8 linter only lint .py files

Tags: python, sublimetext, flake8, sublimelinter

Is there a way to have my SublimeLinter flake8 linter only run on `*.py` files? I know there is an `exclude` key in the settings where I can specify files to ignore, but I'm looking for something more like an `include` setting so I can disable flake8 linting on all non-python files.

My linter settings:

```
    "linters":
    {
        "flake8": {
            "args": ["--ignore=E251,E501"],
            "disable": false,
            "disable_if_not_dependency": false,
            "env": {},
            "excludes": [],
            "executable": "~/miniconda3/bin/flake8",
            "filter_errors": [],
            "lint_mode": "background",
            "python": 3,
            "selector": "",
            "styles": [{"codes": [""]}],
            "working_dir": ""
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [the SublimeLinter docs](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/stable/linter_settings.html#selector-1):

you'd set `selector`.  this appears to use the textmate selector syntax so you'd want to select something like:

```json
    "selector": "source.python",
```

matching the textmate selector [from the python grammar](https://github.com/MagicStack/MagicPython/blob/2802ded681e0ab1a1057821c1da287147d639505/grammars/MagicPython.cson#L3):

```
scopeName: "source.python"
```